# Give a block of text, some keyshorts, and the target text, how to get the minimal key press to convert the text?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have some text(code):

```
  def text = ParamMenuable.this.linkText
  def locPath: List[LocPath] = ParamMenuable.this.path
  def parser = ParamMenuable.this.parser
  def listToFrom(in: List[String]): Box[String] = in.headOption
```

And some keyshorts:

```
arrow-left/right/up/down:  move cursor to left/right/up/down for one char

ctrl + d: duplicate current line
ctrl + arrow-left/right/up/down:  move cursor to left/right/up/down for one word
ctrl + y: delete current line
... all kinds of key shorts you usually used
```

And the target text is:

```
  def text() = {
     ParamMenuable.this.linkText
  }
  def locPath: List[LocPath] = ParamMenuable.this.path
  def locPath22222: List[LocPath] = ParamMenuable.this.path
  private def parser = {
      return ParamMenuable.this.parser;
  }
```

My question is: How many key shorts you should press at least to convert the source text to the target? You can choose proper key shorts to do it better.

Comment: Funny, it is somehow an extension of the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) extended with macros that are reachable by hotkeys. It will really depend on what are the transformations that are reachable through hotkeys. Then, you have to try to list them (copy/paste is one them, but the others ?).

Comment: Sounds like a search problem. I would implement an A*-Search to find an optimal solution.

Comment: I tried nothing, because I don't know anything to do now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably NP-hard. [This paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220657979_Edit_distance_with_move_operations) gives a hardness proof for an editor where insertions, deletions, and substring moves all have constant cost.

```
%0 Book Section
%D 2002
%@ 978-3-540-43862-5
%B Combinatorial Pattern Matching
%V 2373
%S Lecture Notes in Computer Science
%E Apostolico, Alberto
%E Takeda, Masayuki
%R 10.1007/3-540-45452-7_9
%T Edit Distance with Move Operations
%U http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45452-7_9
%I Springer Berlin Heidelberg
%8 2002-01-01
%A Shapira, Dana
%A Storer, JamesA.
%P 85-98
%G English
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that comes close would be the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Still, it works on strings only, not on 2-D areas filled with text.

However, the following should be possible:

```
possible
postibla
```

Here, the Levenshtein distance should be 2 (because 2 characters must be changed to turn "possible" into "postibla"), but it should also be possible to print a trace of the changes one must perform to do the change, like:

```
change 's' on position 4 to 't'
change 'e' on position 8 to 'a'
```

and, in turn, to change this into a series of cursor movements, etc. like (assuming the curser is leftmost in the beginning):

```
-> -> -> DEL 't' -> -> -> DEL $ 'a'
```

(here, the symbol `$` expresses the fact that the cursor is on the end of the line.)
We can then apply optimization rules like:

```
(->)+$     =>   END
(->)+DEL$  =>   END BS
```

and so on.

Just ideas ....